# Oracle Java SQL Exception Error: ORA-0094

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to write a function for this button. I want to be able to pass it a textfield value and be able to go into my database to retrieve some information.....

Can somebody explain to me what is going on and provide me a solution to this madness?

Thank you all xD

I keep running into this stupid problem:

```
 ACTION1 createdoracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@484845aa

 Exception:java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00904: "ART": invalid identifier
```

Code:

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //CLASS TYPE 
    //LIST ALL OFFERED CLASSES AND REVENUE


    try{
        String classtype = jTextField1.getText().trim();
        if(classtype.equals("")){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Sorry Wrong input.... Please try again....");
        }
        else if(classtype != ""){
            try
            {
                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
                    Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@fourier.cs.iit.edu:1521:orcl",
                    "usr","pwd");
                    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                    System.out.println("ACTION1 created"+conn+"\n\n");


                    String ct = jTextField1.getText().trim();
                    //String aa = "SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE="+classtype;
                    //System.out.println(aa);

                    ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE="+ct);
                    while (rset.next()) { 
                        System.out.println(rset.getString("TITLE") + " ");
                    }

                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Class Type: "+classtype);


                    stmt.close();
                    conn.close();
                    System.out.println("Connection Closed");
            }
            catch(Exception sqle){
                    System.out.println("\nException:"+sqle);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Please Retry input....", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

Comment: You add the content of the textfield to you SQL String (ABSOLUTE NOGO! SQL injection vulnerability!), so what is the content of `ct` when the exception is thrown?

Comment: as @Andreas_D said you're not using the prepared statement right. But anyway if you concatenate a string it needs to be within two `'`, ie-  `"SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE='"+ct+"'"` (but better solution is to add params to the prepared statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the value as part of the query, and the string concatenation you're doing makes the SQL into:

```
SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE=ART
```

(where `ART` is the value of `ct` from the textfield) so it's trying to find a column on the table called `ART`. At an *absolute* minimum you need to quote the string:

```
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE='" + ct + "'");
```

But really don't do this; as @Andreas_D says you're leaving yourself open to SQL injection. Always use prepared statements and bind variables:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE=?";
PrepareStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stmt.setString(1, ct);
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me guess ... does the `ct` String start with "ART" (or some variation)?

If so, the problem is that SQL requires quotes around string literals.  Your query probably looks to Oracle something like this:

```
    SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE=Art of War
```

but it should look like

```
    SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE='Art of War'
```

There are two ways to fix this:

1. Assemble the query with quote characters around `ct`.
2. Write the query as `"SELECT * FROM CLASS WHERE TYPE=?"`, use a `PreparedStatement` instead of a `Statement` and use the `setString` method to supply the parameter value.

If done properly, the second approach is both more secure and more efficient.  (The problem with string-bashing the query and using `Statement` is that you are potentially making yourself vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.)